# Parse string using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to parse this string using javascript, How to do this

```
[ +919999999999, +919999999999].
```

I want to display output as  +919999999999

and   +919999999999

Comment: what have u done ?? and just `parse` makes no sense at all...

Comment: What do you want from the string ?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = "[ +919999999999, +919999999999]";

var val = str.replace('[','').replace(']','').split(',');
alert(val[0]); //+919999999999
```

Comment: This works fine, But i am getting data dynamically How to add "" to string

Comment: how are you getting this dynamically? why would you want to add ""?

Comment: var a = window.MyCls.getDRSCounts1();  In "a" variable i am getting this data [  +919999999999,  +919999999999].

Comment: can you try `alert(a[0])` if it gives you something?

Comment: for static i got the data but dynamically i didn't get the data

Comment: that depends on the process... it might be that you are trying to get it earlier than when the data is ready...

Comment: I am getting data as alert. after that i have to print a[0] the whole string is coming

Answer (score 0):

if string, use replace to repalce `[]` and split it...

```
var data= "[ +919999999999, +919999999999]".
var generatedValue = data.replace('[','').replace(']','').split(',');
alert(generatedValue[0]); //alerts  +919999999999 
alert(generatedValue[1]); //alerts +919999999999
```

if array (which looks like one...), use `[index]` to get that
try this

```
var data= "[ +919999999999, +919999999999]".
alert(data[0]); //alerts +919999999999
alert(data[1]); //alerts +919999999999
```